# Bad sound in Ubuntu 18.04 except Firefox

Tags: 18.04, sound

I am pretty much a beginner with desktop linux and I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my newly bought Lenovo P51s. Works fine besides a strange sound problem:

- Sound output (internal speakers) is at very low volume and the sound quality is terribly poor (like out of a tin can) when played from Chrome/Chromium, Rhytmbox, VLC, etc.
- But: Volume and quality is fine when played from Firefox
- If any source besides Firefox is already playing sound, sound from Firefox is also bad.
- `pavucontrol` shows same level for all applications. Moving beyond 100% leads to distortion.
- `alsamixer`: all 100%

My audio device is a

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC298 Analog [ALC298 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #
```

Any suggestions? Is this a known issue? What kind of information should i additionally provide?

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 solved to issue for me.